# Tricky Java Generics : generic class implementing non generic interface with generic Method

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code [as seen in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4om8jH):

```
import java.util.*;

class Test{
   interface Visitor{
        public <T> void visit(T Value);
   }

   class MyVisitor<T> implements Visitor{
        List<T> list = new  ArrayList<T>();

        public <T> void visit(T value){
           list.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled this code will produce the following+ error:

```
 Main.java:12: error: no suitable method found for add(T#1)
             list.add(value);
                 ^
     method List.add(int,T#2) is not applicable
       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
     method List.add(T#2) is not applicable
       (actual argument T#1 cannot be converted to T#2 by method invocation conversion)   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
     T#1 extends Object declared in method visit(T#1)
     T#2 extends Object declared in class Test.MyVisitor 1 error
```

The problem is that the **type T in visit** is not considered the same  **T in list** . How can I fix this compilation problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class MyVisitor<T> implements Visitor{
    List<T> list = new  ArrayList<T>();

    public <T> void visit(T value){
       list.add(value);
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class MyVisitor<T> implements Visitor{
    List<T> list = new  ArrayList<T>();

    public <V> void visit(V value){
       list.add(value);
    }
}
```

i.e. the `T` parameter to the class and the `T` parameter to the `visit` method are not related, and neither is necessarily assignable to the other.  If `Visitor` were itself a parameterized interface

```
interface Visitor<V>{
    public void visit(V Value);
}
```

then you could have `MyVisitor<T> implements Visitor<T>` and the T's *would* then be the same.

Remember that the point of generic methods is to link the types of two or more parameters, or to link the type of a parameter to the return type of the method (e.g. a method that takes a parameter of some type and returns a List of *the same type*).  When a generic method only uses its parameter once it doesn't really gain anything from being generic, i.e. you would get just as much type safety from

```
interface Visitor{
    public void visit(Object Value);
}
```

as you would from your original `Visitor` interface.

Comment: This also will not compile

Comment: @Andremoniy This answer explains what OP really did in his code with alternative example so of course it will also not compile.

Comment: And if I could not alter `Visitor` interface? Would I have to use a raw type List since I would not able to match the `T`  and after erasure `T` would be `Object`?

Comment: @Ian Roberts  [This](http://ideone.com/tCc9yA) says I would go back to the "unchecked"  warnings

Comment: @AndréOriani the only way to do it with no warnings and no `@SuppressWarnings` would be to have a constructor `MyVisitor(Class<T> cls)` and pass in at runtime the `Class` object corresponding to the type parameter of `MyVisitor`, then in `visit` do `list.add(cls.cast(value));`  This would compile but it would still fail at runtime if `visit` was called with a parameter of the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

The interface has to be `Visitor<T>`

Edit: The interface has to look like this

```
interface Visitor<T> {
    void visit(T Value);
}
```

Comment: Not really, that would make things even more confusing because of the generic type parameter shadowing

Comment: The think the suggestion is to make the method generic in the class' `T`.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that you also had to get rid of the generic method definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the generic type `<T>` twice:

- on the `visit` method
- on the `MyVisitor` class

The compiler prevents the adding to the list: `list.add(value);` as the two types might be different.

One way to solve the problem is to make the `Visitor` interface generic in `<T>` and remove the `<T>` on the visit method:

```
interface Visitor<T> {
        public void visit(T Value);
    }

class MyVisitor<T> implements Visitor<T>{
    List<T> list = new  ArrayList<T>();

    public  void visit(T value){
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution will be:

```
class Test {
    interface Visitor<T> {
        public void visit(T Value);
    }

    class MyVisitor<T> implements Visitor<T> {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        @Override
        public void visit(T value) {
           list.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing the type parameter `T` in `MyVisitor<T>` (and thus the type of items in `list`) with the one in the method signature, which can be a different type altogether. (Any type passed to `visit()` which can be any type and might as well be `Object`.) You should rename one or the other.

In fact, the method signature in the visitor is inane as far as Java generics are concerned. Just make it `void visit(Object o)`, it's exactly equivalent and less confusing. Doing so also makes the problem clearer, you're trying to add an `Object` to a `List<T>`. If you need the method signature in `Visitor` to be that, you'll have to cast. (Which will require a `Class.cast()` and thus a `Class<T>` somewhere in `MyVisitor`)